# Wrong mapping of slides in swiper js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I'm getting information about bestsellers. But after mapping of it the props data are mixed between slides. first slide get info from the second slide but get his own image, second slide get info get info from third slide but image is correct.
code of my slider look like this

```
<Slider>
            {slides.length >= 4 && (
              <PrevArrowBox>
                <PrevButton onClick={prevSlideHandler} />
              </PrevArrowBox>
            )}

            <SliderBox limited={slides.length === 1}>
              <Swiper
                onSwiper={setSliderInstance}
                spaceBetween={30}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                loop
                modules={[Pagination]}
                breakpoints={{
                  600: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                  },
                  900: {
                    slidesPerView: slides.length < 3 ? slides.length : 3,
                  },
                }}>
                {slides.map((slide, index) => (
                  <SwiperSlide key={'bestseller_' + index}>
                    <CardWrapper>
                      <Card data={slide} />
                    </CardWrapper>
                  </SwiperSlide>
                ))}
              </Swiper>
            </SliderBox>
            {slides.length >= 4 && (
              <NextArrowBox>
                <NextButton onClick={nextSlideHandler} />
              </NextArrowBox>
            )}
          </Slider>
```

ard that i use look like that

```
<BestSellerCard url={'/' + url} image={imageData}>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <Info>
          <Tittle dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: category }} />
          <Subtitle dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: name }} />
          <Price dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${price}€` }} />
        </Info>
        <CTA>
          <CTAText dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "Hier geht's zum Produkt" }} />
          <CTAIcon aria-label="show more information" />
        </CTA>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </BestSellerCard>
```

I've tied to set data out of component in regular jsx but nothing happened. i've remove loop from slider it help me, but i need loop in this slider.